# Proof by induction with summation

Tags: summation, induction, riemann-sum

I have this math problem that I am stuck on.

> Prove by induction on $n$ that
>    $$\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}{\frac{1}{j}>\frac{n}{2}}$$

What I have so far is check for $n=0$ (base case) $\sum_{j=1}^{1}{\frac{1}{j}} = 1 > 0$.

Then I assume $\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}{\frac{1}{j}>\frac{n}{2}}$ is true for all $n\ge 0$.

I then show it is true for $n+1$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}>\frac{n+1}{2}}$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n}}{\frac{1}{j} + \sum_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} >\frac{n+1}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{n}{2} + \sum_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} >\frac{n+1}{2}$$

$$= \sum_{j=2^n}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} > \frac{1}{2}$$

I'm stuck here. thanks.

Comment: Subtract $n/2$ from both sides – you'll then have to show that $ \sum_{j = 2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}} 1/j > 1/2 $. What do you know about the function $1/j$?

Comment: @amcerbu I know that $\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}{\frac{1}{j}>\frac{n}{2}}$? How does that help?

Comment: Hint: there are $2^n$ terms in your sum, and each is greater than or equal to $1/(2^{n+1})$.

Comment: @amcerbu So, the lowest term I can have is $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Still not 100% where to go. Thanks.

Comment: So that means your sum is greater than the sum of $2^n$ terms equal to $1/(2^{n+1})$, i.e. $2^n / (2^{n+1}) = 1/2$.

Comment: @amcerbu So, you're saying $\sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} = \frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}$?

Comment: Almost. $1/2 = \sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1{2^{n+1}} \le \sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac1j$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31429/discussion-between-kfc-and-amcerbu).

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522059/use-induction-to-prove-that-sum-k-12n-frac1k-geq-1-fracn2/1522061#1522061

Answer (score 1):

Notice that what you actually need to show is

$$ \sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} > \frac{1}{2} .$$

This follows from the fact that, since

$$\frac{1}{j} \geq \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \; \text{ for all } j \in \{2^n+1,\dots,2^{n+1}\},$$

with strict inequality for all $j < 2^{n+1}$, then

$$ \sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}}{\frac{1}{j}} > 2^n \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}.$$