# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{k}\ge 1+\frac{n}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I want to prove this statement for $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}\space $by induction:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{k}\ge 1+\frac{n}{2}$$

**Step 1:** $n=1$

$$\implies1+\frac{1}{2}\le1+\frac{1}{2} \checkmark$$

**Step 2:** Assume the inequality holds for some $m$. Show that it holds for $m+1$

$$\implies \sum_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \frac{1}{k} \ge 1+\frac{m+1}{2} \\ \iff \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k}}+\frac{1}{2^{m+1}} \ge \color{blue}{1+\frac{m}{2}}+ \frac{1}{2}$$

I assumed the inequalitie holds for $m$ (the blue part). To show that it holds for $m+1$ I have to show that $$\frac{1}{2^{m+1}} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$
However, this statement is false for all $m>1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522059/use-induction-to-prove-that-sum-k-12n-frac1k-geq-1-fracn2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}} \frac1k$$ is **not** equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$$

It is, in fact, equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac{1}{k} +\color{red}{ \frac{1}{2^m+1} + \frac{1}{2^m+2} +\cdots}+ \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}.$$

You missed some (actually, almost half of all) summands. To conclude your proof, think about *how many* summands there are in the above expression (the ones in red and the last one).

Comment: Oh I see. But if I have something like $\sum_1^5 \frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}$ isn't that the same as saying $\sum_1^4 \frac{1}{k}+ \frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: @Nullspace Yes. But you aren't comparing $\sum_1^4$ and $\sum_1^5$. You are comparing $\sum_1^{2^4}$ and $\sum_1^{2^5}$, which is $\sum_1^{16}$ and $\sum_1^{32}$.

Comment: Okay that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you very much. Could you maybe recommend some online resources where I can practice questions like these a bit more. I am quite bad at this and I would like to get better.

Comment: @Nullspace Any one of a number of calculus books is the way to go. Online... I don't know, but even if you find something online, the only way to solve it is to grab a pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac1k=\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac1k+\sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac1k.$$You are assuming that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{2^m}\frac1k\geqslant1+\frac m2$. Now, use the fact that$$\sum_{k=2^m+1}^{2^{m+1}}\frac1k\geqslant2^m\times\frac1{2^{m+1}}=\frac{2^m}{2^{m+1}}=\frac12.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand why the summs starts from $k=2^m+1$ and not from $2^{m+1}$ or is that a typo?

Comment: No, it is not a typo. What is the first number after $2^m$? Isn't it $2^m+1$?

Comment: Ah I think I get it. I am basically increasing the upper bound of the summation by $1$ at the time so $2^m+1...2^m+2....2^{m+1}$

Comment: I have one more question. How did you arrive at the conclusion that the last sum is $\ge 2^m \times \frac{1}{2^{m+1}}$?

Comment: Bucause whe we sum all elements of a finite set $A$, that sum is greater than or equal to$$\#A\times(\text{smallest element of }A).$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}1/k=$

$1+1/2 + (1/3+1/4)+(1/5+16/+1/7+1/8)+....$

$+( 1/(2^{n-1}+1)+......1/2^n) \ge $

$1+1/2 +2/4 +4/8+.............+(2^n-2^{n-1})/(2^n)=$

$1+ 1/2+1/2...........1/2 =$

($n$ summands $1/2$)

$1+n/2.$